# date range is out of month

Tags: python, pandas

I have this date:

```
31-Apr-2020
```

It definitely gives this error:

```
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: day is out of range for month: 31-Apr-2020
```

How do I put an exception on it? This is my code;

```
hist_df["ArticleDate_s"] = pd.to_datetime(hist_df["ArticleDate_s"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: pass `errors='coerce'` in `to_datetime()` method